# What does "|" mean in a terminal command line?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Sorry for posting it here, but Google does a very bad job when searching for symbols.

What does the "|" mean in:

```
"some string" | someexecutable.py
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Comment: The `bash` man page explains the behaviour in great detail - is there something you didn't understand there?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is the pipe symbol.  It separates two programs on a command line (see [`Pipelines`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) in the `bash` manual), and the standard output of the first program (on the LHS of the pipe) is connected to the standard input of the second program (on the RHS of the pipe).

For example:

```
who | wc -l
```

gives you a count of the number of people or sessions connected to your computer (plus one for the header line from `who`).  To discount the header line:

```
who | sed 1d | wc -l
```

The input to `sed` comes from `who`, and the output of `sed` goes to `wc`.

The underlying system call is [`pipe(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) used in conjunction with [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) and the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) system calls.

Comment: Note that when it is combined with other characters, the `|` symbol has different meanings.  In 'all' shells, `||` is a logical connective.  It executes the first command; if it exits with a non-zero (failure) status, it executes the second command too.  In Bash (and maybe some other shells), `|&` is a variant of `|` that sends standard error as well as standard output to the next command in the pipeline.  Sometimes, interpreting a sequence of symbols is hard (`ls|<xml>html mapper` probably doesn't do what you might think).

Answer (score 13):

It's called [`pipe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). It gives the stdout of the first command (`"some string"`) as the stdin to the second command (`someexecutable.py`).

Answer (score 7):

| is a pipe. It sends output of one command as input of the next. It is explained here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-4/#3-pipes